# insert a large amount of data into RDB tables in Teiid

Tags: teiid

does someone know how to use SQL sentence, like "insert into table values (...) select ... " in teiid to insert large-scale data into relations/tables of RDBs as effect as jdbc batch?

-Zhen

In a task, I need to first use SQL select query to collect a large amount of data, and then insert the answers obtained into a table of a RDB source.